# I am getting error while trying to login through valid email and password,which is stored in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I am trying to login through a email and password of the user which is already present in the database.But when i am filling the login_form and clicking on login button it is showing an error,as present in the image    [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFO0X.png).
Terminal screenshoot:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc4SI.png)

```
**new.html.erb**

        <%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>
                                                <div class="form-group"  style="margin-top:20px;">
                                                    <%= f.label :email %>
                                                    <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group"  style="margin-top:20px;">
                                                    <%= f.label :password %>
                                                    <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:20px;"> 

                                                    <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-primary btn-block" %>
                                                </div>
                                            <% end %>
    **session_controller.rb**
    class SessionsController < ApplicationController
        def new
        end
        def create
            user = User.find_by(email: session_params[:email].downcase)
            puts User.find_by(email: session_params[:email].downcase)
            puts user
            puts user.id
            puts user.password
            puts session_params[:password]
            if user && user.password ==(session_params[:password])
                log_in user
                redirect_to user_path(user.id)
            else
                flash[:success] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
                render 'new'
            end
        end
        def destroy
            log_out
            redirect_to root_url
        end
         private

      def session_params
        params.require(:session).permit(:email, :password)
      end
    end
**route.rb**
Rails.application.routes.draw do
get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
    post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
    delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'
    resources :sessions
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User
    include Mongoid::Document
        attr_accessor :password
        field :name, type: String
        field :category, type: String
        field :email, type: String
        field :password, type: String
        validates :name, presence: true ,format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/} 
        validates :email, presence: true , format: { with: /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i } , uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false } 
        validates :password , presence: true 
        before_save :downcase_fields
        def downcase_fields
            self.name.downcase!
            self.category.downcase!
            self.email.downcase!
        end
end
```

Comment: try to reset the password from console and then try to login

Comment: since you are using `puts` to display in logs, do the values match?

Comment: how to reset the password @AniketShivamTiwari

Comment: result in terminal is,where user.password is coming as a blank ,as shown in the fourth line @Md.FarhanMemon :                                                                                                              #<User:0x007f22655a7600>
#<User:0x007f22655f6570>
590e5f9b357afd0e0773ebe8

123456

Comment: Open rails console then type User.find_by(email: "type-email-here").update_attributes(password: 'type-the-password')

Comment: I tried it but the same error is coming @AniketShivamTiwari

Comment: did you open rails console?

Comment: there are 5 puts and you shared 4 outputs. what is `590e5f9b357afd0e0773ebe8` this for?

Comment: yah i know it @AniketShivamTiwari and after updating the attribute i also clarified with the db and it was updated there.

Comment: No, i told you ,fourth puts user.password is not printing anything @Md.FarhanMemon

Comment: so what is the problem now ? When you are able to reset the password from console so try to login with new passong then

Comment: I tried @AniketShivamTiwari but same error is coming.There is no chnage in the error.

Comment: Have you seen the session_controller.rb @AniketShivamTiwari,i am using 5 puts but it is printing only 4 and user.password is not getting printed on the terminal

Comment: share your terminal screenshot

Comment: yah ,sure,please have a look on it

Comment: I had shared the terminal screenshots please have a look on it @Md.FarhanMemon

Comment: Once you fix that, your next improvement should be to __not store passwords in plain text!__ Use `has_secure_password` at least.

Comment: Ok, i got it @SergioTulentsev,but help me in fixing the current problem.

Comment: are you able to get that user from the console by doing `User.where(email: ENTER_EMAIL_HERE, password: '123456').first`?

Comment: I think the user which you are trying to login doesn't has password. can you please do `User.find_by(email: "angad1@gmail.com").first.password` and share me the out put here?

Comment: Or try to login with the that password.

Comment: One more thing i observed, For same user you entered password `123456` and `987654321` for first and second times according to terminal screenshot. Which means you don't know the exact password stored in DB. please check correctly and do login. It works.

Comment: Yes @Md.FarhanMemon,i can able to get the hash containing the details of the user.

Comment: after trying your statement , i can able to get the password @NarasimhaReddy.So, password is also present.That password login is also giving same error.

Comment: I know the password but someone suggested me to change the password and try to login with new password @NarasimhaReddy

Comment: oop's. Okay. if posible share me the `User` model here. Will  try to debug?

Comment: heyy, try this `redirect_to user_path(user) and return`.

Comment: please have a look on it,i am sharing user.rb @NarasimhaReddy

Comment: I tried @Md.FarhanMemon,but the error is same.Please have a look on model i had shared.Help me in fixing the thing.

Comment: Possible problem is, You might have many users with same emailId(anagd1@gmail.com) with diffrent passwords. So `find_by` always returns random record. That might be the problem. please check that by typing `User.where(email: angad1@gmail.com).count`.

Comment: No only single email is present with the email id mentioned above,there is no duplication because , i am using                                            validates :email, presence: true , format: { with: /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i } , uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

Comment: Yes off course but there might be a chance that a user has been created before adding unique constraint on email. that's why i asked you to check. :).  okay. i'll let you know if i find anything else.

Comment: this is my collection, i hope there is no duplication  @ Narasimha Reddy                                                                            { "_id" : ObjectId("590e5f9b357afd0e0773ebe8"), "name" : "angad", "category" : "student", "email" : "angad1@gmail.com", "password" : "987654321" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("590f7097357afd5a0d58eed1"), "name" : "tej", "category" : "student", "email" : "tej@gmail.com", "password" : "123456"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey just remove `attr_accessor :password` from model. It works

```
class User
    include Mongoid::Document
        attr_accessor :password//remove this line
        field :name, type: String
        field :category, type: String
        field :email, type: String
        field :password, type: String
        validates :name, presence: true ,format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/} 
        validates :email, presence: true , format: { with: /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i } , uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false } 
        validates :password , presence: true 
        before_save :downcase_fields
        def downcase_fields
            self.name.downcase!
            self.category.downcase!
            self.email.downcase!
        end
end
```

`field :password` will create setter and getter methods for that field which involves in `.save` operation. But you are overriding `mongoid` default getter method using `attr_accessor :password`.

it will be like

```
def password
  @password
end
```

here `@password` is just a instance variable on `User` model. it will be `nil` always(because you are not setting any value to it). that's why it was not working.

Comment: What is the reason that it was not working earlier and after removing attr_accessor,it started working fine @narasimha reddy

Comment: Updated answer. please check @AbhaySharma